# How do I clear the browser cache programmatically on the iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, basecamp

I am using the new Basecamp API for my iOS basecamp client app. I want the user to be able to logout and switch accounts. But I can't as the account credentials stored in the browser cache are used every time I request authorization.

I figured out I would need to flush browser cache to do this. How do I clear the browser cache?

Comment: How are you doing authentication?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

After that, you can deleting any associated cookies with in the UIWebView:

```
for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {

    if([[cookie domain] isEqualToString:someNSStringUrlDomain]) {

        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
}
```

Comment: @shyambhat, Would it only work `UIWebView` within the app or it can work for Mobile Safari too ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Romit for your solution :)

Comment: Not works in my case. I am working on one application in which i have to fetch all emails of outlook user. After login successfully i get all emails listing. But when i try to login by different user that time it display first user data. Due to that unable to login by different user.